# firefoxdriver running exception some times used by selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

these's my java code.

```html
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
for (DBTable table : tables) {
 try {
  Thread.sleep(10000l);
  String content = templeteService.generateTemplate(table);
  content = content.replaceAll("\\r|\\n|\\t", "");
  String title = table.getComment();
  //跳转到内容父页面
  driver.get(topUrl);
  String curUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl();
  //如果重定向到登录页，则登录
  if (curUrl.indexOf("/confluence/login.action") != -1) {
   driver.findElement(By.id("os_username")).sendKeys("kehui");
   driver.findElement(By.id("os_password")).sendKeys("kehui.1225");
   driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
  }
  //点击创建按钮
  driver.findElement(By.id("create-page-button")).click();
  //点击生成默认的空白页
  driver.findElement(By.className("create-dialog-create-button")).click();
  Thread.sleep(1000l);
  //wiki标题
  driver.findElement(By.id("content-title")).sendKeys(title);
  //切换到wiki内容页，并填充标题
  driver.switchTo().frame("wysiwygTextarea_ifr");
  WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
  JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  jsExecutor.executeScript("document.body.innerHTML = '" + content + "';", editor);
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  //driver.findElement(By.id("notifyWatchers")).click();
  //点击发布按钮
  //driver.findElement(By.id("rte-button-publish")).click();
 } catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("exception-" + table.getTableName(), e);
 }
}
driver.close();
DBUtil.closeConn();
```

running exception info.

```css
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Build info: version: '2.49.1', revision: '808c23b0963853d375cbe54b90bbd052e2528a54', time: '2016-01-21 09:37:52'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-RHNIR30', ip: '10.7.242.80', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
 at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp/anonymous912190740134287098webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10003)
 at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp/anonymous912190740134287098webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12540)
 at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp/anonymous912190740134287098webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12557)
 at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_(file:///D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp/anonymous912190740134287098webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12562)
 at <anonymous class>.DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<(file:///D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.64/temp/anonymous912190740134287098webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12504)
2016-01-25 16:04:37,292 ERROR (com.manyi.iw.test.sth.service.impl.WikiServiceImpl:99) - exception-iw_sale_contract_customer_doc
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.49.1', revision: '808c23b0963853d375cbe54b90bbd052e2528a54', time: '2016-01-21 09:37:52'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-RHNIR30', ip: '10.7.242.80', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: 413945ea-a8db-4b69-9f34-3868c540174d
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=43.0.4}]
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:122)
 at com.manyi.iw.test.sth.service.impl.WikiServiceImpl.autoPublishWiki(WikiServiceImpl.java:88)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
 at com.manyi.iw.test.sth.interceptor.ExceptionInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionInterceptor.java:21)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
```

exception occured not always, sometiems.

it occured when a button click for a new page but loading, chrome driver can't find the new page document, an exception occured.

how to running complete without firefoxdriver exception. help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use explicit wait with [expected conditions](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("id"));
element.click();
```

This will wait up to 20 seconds for the element to be visible. After that the element will be visible and you shouldn't have problem interacting with it.

Comment: hey, guy. another question, how to know an ajax action excute complete in the same page?  now, exception occued sometimes, less than ago. i guess it occured when i get the element in a pannel visible, the panel visible after an ajax action complete.

Comment: @C.Ke I'm not familiar with ajax, take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)

Comment: Okay, i see. i try to use another method. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax calls (question asked in the other answer thread), if a loading indicator is displayed while waiting for data, you can wait for the loading indicator to be not visible.